# Get xyz of sphere that is moused over three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am generating a bunch of spheres using three.js through an array and a for loop. The original array looks like:

```
atoms = [
 ['Na', [0, 0, 0]],
 ['Na', [0.5, 0.5, 0]],
 ['Na', [0.5, 0, 0.5]],
 ['Na', [0, 0.5, 0.5]],
 ['Cl', [0.5, 0, 0]],
 ['Cl', [0, 0.5, 0]],
 ['Cl', [0, 0, 0.5]],
 ['Cl', [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]],
];
```

And i parse the data so that the 3 numbers represent the x, y, z coordinate.

The end product is controlled by orbitcontrols.js and looks like: [image]

What I was wondering is how would I go about doing this: mouse over a sphere (while pressing a certain key as to not interfere with orbitcontrols) then upon a mouse click return the xyz of the sphere i clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you will need to add some eventListeners for the keydown, keyup and mousedown events:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
```

You can add these eventListeners in your scene, or in some class. For the keyup and keydown you need to lookup the keyCode you want to use.

For the click event you need to use the THREE.Raycaster. You could use something like this as a start:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 1, 10000);
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

    for (var i=1; i<=16; i++) {
        var intersect = raycaster.intersectObject(spheres[i]);
        if (intersect.length > 0) {
            console.log(spheres[i].position);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to tweak the vector if you are not using fullscreen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It definitely helped, could you please explain in layman's terms what is going on? Am I creating a vector that comes out of my mouse and wherever it intersects with an object it logs it?